# Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network but Why?

Tags: ios, ipv6

One of version of an app rejected with this message ***Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network***. The problem is the application has not a single network function or functionality so I am unable to understand whats going on.

This was the 4th version of application, old versions was on store. At last version we just removed an issue causing  the application fail text to speech in new iOS versions.

Comment: may be the library you are using doesnt support ipv6 connection, where as , the tester in apple tests your app in ipv6 connection and in ipad..
so the first step you need to take is.. set up your local ipv6 network and test your app yourself, where is the crash taking place..
check this link
https://www.cyberfreewishes.com/blog/how-to-setup-local-ipv6-network-using-mac#.WpzxAiOB3OQ
to set up your ipv6 hotspot

Comment: It may be nothing to do with IPv6, they are simply telling you about the environment where they tested your app.  You need to [symbolicate the provided crash report](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) to identify where the crash occurred.

Comment: Yes but application does not crash at that iOS version when I was testing and I do not have IPv6 network connection. At my test, devices was connected LAN and/or cellular data network.

Comment: Apple also has a tech note on [IPv6 testing](https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/) but start with the crashlog that they will have supplied. It doesn't matter that it doesn't crash for you; it crashed for them; work out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a similar note to the Apple and they approved application after sometime. I think problem was not my application this time.

Comment: Hi, could I know which notes did you write to apple that proceed your app to live. Will you share ?

Comment: @Jogendra.Com, I wrote following message at resolution center. Dear Sirs, We will revise and test app again but it is interesting that app fails when connected IPV6 network. Because app has no functionality about networks in anyway.

Comment: I wrote in similar terms than @Hope and I'm trying to buy time