# Guideline 2.1 - Performance Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

I just submitted my app to iTunes Connect and it got rejected saying "Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review."
I made this game using Unity3D engine.

Comment: So, what are we supposed to do about that?

Comment: 1.What's your Unity version? 2.Are you doing any network stuff(using socket)?

Comment: 2017.3.0p2 and no I don't use any socket, its a game I use GameCenter for IOS and google play for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try searching for previous solutions first? That can be helpful, as a quick google search revealed this right here on SO:

[Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network but Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105332/your-app-crashed-on-ipad-or-iphone-running-ios-11-2-5-connected-to-an-ipv6-netwo)

In that situation, the user 'Hope' has an iOS application that is neither usually unstable or having any network functionality at all. That means that the IPv6 note may just mean the review conditions, not specifically your app's debug. And in fact, a nearly identical previous version of their app was approved. So the fault was ambiguous.

In that situation, 'Hope' sent Apple a note and the application was approved. I suggest you could try the same. At the very least, it's a good starting point. But apart from that, with the info you've given, there's not much else we can help with.